# Export to excel(xlsx) in dynamic rad grid

Tags: c#, excel, telerik-grid

I have an issue with the date format while exporting data from radGrid to excel,"December 2014" in the grid is converted to "Dec-2014" in the exported excel. I read a few links and found out that this custom formatting can be done in radGrid_ExportCellFormatting event handler. Like :

```
protected void radGrid_ExportCellFormatting(object source, ExportCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
   if ((e.FormattedColumn.UniqueName) == "Content")
    {
        e.Cell.Style["mso-number-format"] = @"\@";//To export in text format
    }
}
```

Since I am forming the grid dynamically, I added the event to grid in code behind, but the event is not getting fired.

```
 radGrid.ExportCellFormatting += new EventHandler<ExportCellFormattingEventArgs>(radGrid_ExportCellFormatting);
```

Note: This method fires and works fine when it is not a dynamic grid.

It will be helpful if someone could tell me what I am missing, or is there any other method to set the format for column as "text".

The export method where I am creating the grid for export is:

```
protected void ExportExcel(RadGrid radGrid)
{
        DataSet dsResults = GetDataSet(radGrid);
        if (dsResults != null && dsResults.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            RadGrid radGrid = new RadGrid();
            radGrid.ID = "radGridExcel";
            List<string> colNames = (from DataColumn x in      dsResults.Tables[0].Columns select x.ColumnName).ToList();
            radGrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Clear();
            radGrid.EnableLinqExpressions = false;
            colNames.ForEach(columnName => radGrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(new Telerik.Web.UI.GridBoundColumn { DataField = columnName, HeaderText = columnName, AllowSorting = false, AllowFiltering = false }));
            radGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            radGrid.DataSource = dsResults.Tables[0];
            radGrid.DataBind();
            radGrid.ExportCellFormatting += new EventHandler<ExportCellFormattingEventArgs>(radGrid_ExportCellFormatting);
            this.Controls.Add(radGrid);               
            radGrid.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = GridExcelExportFormat.Xlsx;
            radGrid.ExportSettings.HideStructureColumns = true;
            radGrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
            radGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
            radGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = fileName;
            radGrid.MasterTableView.GroupsDefaultExpanded = true;
            radGrid.MasterTableView.Caption = string.Empty;
            radGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the *radGrid_ExportCellFormatting* has become obsolete at some point in time, you should probably find some other event like *ItemCreated* ..

Comment: But the Grid_ExportCellFormatting exists and is getting fired for a non dynamic grid in the page. So it's not obsolete right?

Comment: There was a discussion somewhere which had a similar scenario, the conclusion was to find alternative events since this one was being made obsolete or didn't work